# How to vertically align two <div> tags perfectly for each resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on the login form for the next time when we update Blackboard, as it will be using a new theme and our current page is not compatible with it. I am not too design savvy or an expert at all at HTML/CSS, I merely know how to use the inspector to do a little investigating and make changes if something is broken. What I'm also not specifically an expert at is knowing how to implement all the specific position details and what not.

So far I've almost got my page just the way I want it but different screen resolutions throw off the rendering. 1920x1200 loads the two boxes in the middle perfectly, but 1440x900 off centers them to the right. I basically want the two boxes(the ones that are outlined)to always center and be right next to each other like they are no matter what screen sizes/resolution.

You can go to https://com-bb-dev.com.edu to see what I have right now and to use the inspector to check out the CSS. Here is what I've tried so far: div.loginBody is on the left and #loginOptions is on the right on the site.

```
div.loginBody 
{
background:url("images/Bb_learn_small.png") no-repeat scroll 65px 21px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.74);
position:relative;
margin-left: 22%;
margin-top: 2%;
padding-top: 175px;
width: 529px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}
```

and

```
#loginOptions 
{
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.72);
position: absolute;
float: right;
margin-left: 101%;
top: -1px;
width: 529px;
height: 392px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move some of your CSS from `.loginBody` to `#loginBox`.  At the same time I would get rid of a lot of that positioning and margin stuff you got going on.

Here is a simplistic jsFiddle using your dimensions: http://jsfiddle.net/vWVD8/
This jsFiddle uses smaller dimensions so you can see how everything is getting centered more clearly as the window for the fiddle is kind of small: http://jsfiddle.net/vWVD8/1/

`margin: 0 auto;` centers everything.  In order for it to work a width must be specified.  Other than that we float our two DIVs to the left so they line up.

*HTML*

```html
<div class="loginBody">
    <div id="loginBox">
        Login Box DIV
    </div>
    <div id="loginOptions">
        Login Options DIV
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```css
.loginBody {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1074px;  /* = div width + margins + borders + padding + etc. */
}
#loginBox,
#loginOptions {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    float: left;
    height: 329px;
    width: 529px;
}
#loginOptions {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm having an issue doing anything with loginBox. I don't want it to stay detached from loginBody. I treat loginBody and loginOptions as their own entire boxes because that makes sense to me and fiddling with the loginBox class is giving me problems. Also, applying this concept doesn't work if I remove position: relative from loginBody. Please advise.

Comment: Ahh, finally getting it. I'm getting close man! It's not perfect yet but I finally have it going the way I want because of your help. Thank you.

Comment: I will mark your response as answered when I can, @hungerstar

Comment: I actually got it after I studied your jsFiddle enough, check out the page when you get a chance. I'll re-add the background + logo tomorrow once I'm at work and now that I understand what's going on.

Comment: For the background logo I would use an `<h1>` or `<h2>` tag or just use a plain old `<img>` tag.  Something like this: `<h1>Blackboard Learn</h1>` placed right after `#loginFormText` with the following CSS `#loginBox h1 { width: 420px; height: 130px; margin: 0 auto; text-indent: -99999em; background-image: url("https://com-bb-dev.com.edu/themes/as_2012/images/Bb_learn_small.png"); padding: 0; }`.  I would also suggest the following: `#loginBox, #loginOptions { width: 479px; padding: 25px; } #loginFormFilds { position: relative; top: -8px;`.

Comment: What benefit would these changes have? When I was referring to the background what I meant was I'm going to shade in the backgrounds of the login form + the options box with white because our marketing dept states that the college brand has to be over white. Are you talking about adding this all to the source page and not the .css file itself? @hungerstar What I need to do if possible is move my login fields for username/pass down so I can re-implement a brand/logo/banner. Any ideas on that?

Comment: The suggestions above can be modified of course but the main point of using `h1` or `h2` is for screen readers.  You could use a `div` as well.  Most every website uses this approach for logos/site names/banners.  The rest of it is to replicate what you had previously for the two DIVs `#loginBox` and `loginOptions`.